# Column level encryption on SQL Azure with logical partition on tables

Tags: security, azure, encryption, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I have tried enabling column level encryption on Azure SQL DB along with Key vault; which is working fine.
But I have a situation where based on the data in the column I want to have different keys for encryption.
Example, I have a [Institution] column and for each institution I want to have different keys (CEK) to encrypt. Is it possible to do this? I was also looking at logical partitioning and then encrypting , for each logical partition it should have separate CEK (Column encryption key).
Can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Always encrypted does not support multiple CEKs for a single column, even with logical partitioning. A column can only have one CEK.

You might want to look at [row level security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx) and determine if that can help your use case.
Row level security provides the access control that you need but the security guarantees provided by row level security are not the same as always encrypted